# Pulling the number of keywords from Google Search results for a particular country to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-api-python-client

Looking for solutions how to retrieve the data for a certain website - the number of keywords that a website has got in top 20 Google search results for a particular country.

I need to get the data to Google sheers like:

[image]

Need to understand from what to start. Is it possible to implement this with Python or JavaScript? Or may be something else?

Comment: Do you have a Google search API key?

Comment: at the moment, no. but I can set it up.

Comment: are you pull from here? https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=AU

Comment: no, I don't need the data from there.

Comment: no, I don't need the data from there. I need the number of keywords a certain site has got in the top 20 google search results for a particular country. for example, https://www.wikipedia.org/ has got 1370 keywords in the top 20 Google search results for the USA, for India - 496, for UK - 483, for Germany 270. This data can be taken manually from Semrush or Ahrefs. But since I am dealing with more than 1000 sites, I would like to automize the whole process.

Comment: You need to provide more details before anyone can help you.  Some rough code would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, any site (like SEMRush or ahrefs) would work as long as you can code a web scraper using something like [Python's selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Node.js](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-javascript/). Some sites like the [Alexa Web Information Service](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=4a9dbf38-88b1-4e87-a459-271154a77d2e) provide APIs which simply the task. Once you have the data, you can use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) to automatically create a Google Sheet with the information you have.

Comment: In other words, this could be implemented with Python's selenium or node.js + Google Sheets API?

Comment: Yes, you can use any web scraper (such as selenium or puppeteer) to obtain the data and the google sheets API to represent your data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Alexa top sites](https://www.alexa.com/topsites) provides you with the desired database. I don't know if they provide APIs.